# How to define type without operations allowed on the underlying type?

Tags: go, types, underlyingtype

If I define a type definition

```
type X int64
```

Why is it that I can then do

```
var x X = 123
x = x + 1
```

The `x` behaves as if it was the underlying `int64`, which I don't want. Or that it allows operations on the underlying type to be performed on this new type?

One of the reasons I'd define a new type is to hide the underlying type and define my own operations on it.

Comment: You can not define or override operators in Go. You may only define methods.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a new [defined type](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_definitions) will dissociate any **methods** on the underlying type, but it does not dissociate functionality with **operators** such as `+ - / *`.

> A defined type may have methods associated with it. It **does not inherit any methods** bound to the given type

You should base your type on an underlying type with the desirable operators. For example, if you don't want to have arithmetic operators, you can derive from a `struct`.

If your type still needs the arithmetic capabilities of an `int64` for internal reasons, you can hide it as an un-exported field in the struct. For example:

```golang
type X struct {
   number int64
}
```